# Average of an array will fail if I have int.MaxValue in the array

Tags: c#

I have defined the following method which calculates the average of an array:

```
public int AverageOfArray (params int[] arr)
        {
            if (arr.Length > 0)
            {
                double avg = Sum(ints) / arr.Length;
                return (int)avg;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

My requirement is that the average should be returned as an integer. When I tried to test this method using the int.MaxValue        The unit test will fail. How can I make the test class pass?

UPDATED::-

```
public int Sum(params int[] arr)
        {
            int total = 0;

            for (int n = 0; n < arr.Length; n++)
            {
                total += arr[n];
            }

            return total;


        }
```

Comment: What does `Sum` look like? (Chances are your integer addition is overflowing; use `long` or `double` instead as your accumulator.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,,,see my update i provide the sum method.

Comment: can't you use the average linq function?

Comment: yes it is a option i will try it also..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Sum` method, the `int` data type is not sufficient to hold the sum of `int.MaxValue / 2` and `int.MaxValue / 2 + 4`:

```
     int.MaxValue / 2     = 0x3FFFFFFF
     int.MaxValue / 2 + 4 = 0x40000003
--------------------------------------
Sum: int.MaxValue - 1 + 4 = 0x80000002 (subtract 1 because int.MaxValue is odd)
```

Because the correct sum exceeds `int.MaxValue`, it overflows into the sign bit, causing the result to be 2<sup>32</sup> less than the correct sum (see [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Addition) on Wikipedia for more information):

```
Correct sum:  2147483650
 Actual sum: -2147483646
```

The actual sum is wrong, so when you divide it by 2, you get the wrong average too. Garbage in, garbage out!

To fix this problem, change the return type of `Sum` to `long`, and change the type of the `total` variable to `long` as well:

```
public long Sum(params int[] arr)
{
    long total = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < arr.Length; n++)
    {
        total += arr[n];
    }
    return total;
}
```

Now the `Sum` method returns the correct sum: `int.MaxValue + 3` is less than `long.MaxValue`, so no overflow occurs.

Comment: Make sure to flush out answers for quick reference.

Comment: i re-evaluate the question again but why the "int data type is not sufficient to hold the sum of int.MaxValue / 2 and int.MaxValue / 2 + 4." baring in mind that the result of this average will be less than intMaxValue, so the int should be able to  hold the result of this average !!!Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
public int AverageOfArray (params int[] arr)
{

    double avg = 0;

    if (arr.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < arr.Length; n++)
        {
            avg += arr[n]/arr.Length;
        }

    }
    return (int)avg;
}
```

Comment: This says the average of 1 and 1 is 0.

Comment: Probably due to an int conversion, i.e 0.5 getting converted to zero. If the array value is cast to a double before dividing by length then it should be okay.